# Center multiple labels when orientation changes?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an iPad screen with a UILabel title and three UILabels immediately below it.  I can center the title by stretching out the dimensions of the title UILabel and centering within the label.  How can I keep the UILabels below it centered when I change orientation?

Visually it should look something like this:

```
                                       My Title
                                   Foo: 10 / Bar: 20
```

Comment: Do you want the spacing between the 3 labels to remain the same? Are your labels defined in interface builder or in code?

Comment: The labels are defined in IB.  I didn't make them one big label and center it because I potentially want the colors of the first and third UILabels to be different.

Comment: do you want the spacing to stay the same between the labels?

Comment: That would be ideal.  The / should be on the center line and the other two labels to the left and right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the 3 labels in a small UIView and configure that view in Interface Builder to always stay centered horizontally (with the autosizing properties, just put all horizontal arrows and lines there to the dashed version instead of solid red).

Of course you need to have "autoresize subviews" on the parent UIView enabled for this to work